# how to write angularjs json object into html

Tags: php, angularjs, json

output of invitation.jobseeker

[{"jobma_pitcher_id":"5","jobma_pitcher_fname":"Neetu","jobma_pitcher_lname":"Juneja","jobma_pitcher_email":"neetur@selectsourceintl.com","email_verified":"0","jobma_pitcher_alt_email":"aghi.neetu@gmail.com","jobma_pitcher_bdate":"1970-01-01","jobma_pitcher_sex":"male","jobma_pitcher_phone":"9650721048","phone_verified":"0","otp":"","jobma_secondary_phone":"9650721048","jobma_pitcher_address":"delta tower, sector 44","jobma_pitcher_city":"7577","jobma_pitcher_state":"425","jobma_pitcher_zip":"121001","jobma_pitcher_fax":"","jobma_pitcher_country":"IN","jobma_pitcher_photo":"/storage/jobseeker_pics/20160601120148.png","jobma_pitcher_profile_status":"0","jobma_pitcher_profile_is_delete":"0","jobma_pitcher_type":"free","jobma_pitcher_qrcode":"/storage/jobseeker_qr/9o5GTqt0~Sw-.png","jobma_pitcher_url":"neetujuneja","jobma_pitcher_url_customized":"1","jobma_referer":"","is_first_login":"0","latitude":"50.8923809","longitude":"4.4442992","ulat":"1","api_key":"sn4Py6Ck0zm5Z3CNEL8R1qTupSK3Zs1460533300","created_at":"2016-04-13 07:41:40","updated_at":"2016-06-01 12:02:04"}]

here m writing like this
{{ invitation.jobseeker.jobma_pitcher_fname }}

but m getting nothing...

Comment: try `{{ invitation.jobseeker[0].jobma_pitcher_fname }}`

Answer (score 1):

seems like your data is an object containing in array. you should try using ng-repeat to get data in the view.
Please have a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat